# C++ CLI Eigen: setting values in Matrix

Tags: matrix, c++-cli, eigen

This is my code.

```
Matrix<int, 240, 240>* imagePixels;
    for (signed int x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
            {
                for (signed int y = 0; y < 100; ++y)
                {   
                    imagePixels(x,y) = y;
                }
            }
```

I want to simply add values to my matrix but it gives me:

```
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

at `matrix(x,y) = y;`
I'm using C++ CLI.

Comment: I don't know much about CLI (read: never heard of it before and no idea what it is), but did you want `imagePixels(x,y)` instead of `matrix(x,y)`?

Comment: @R_Kapp I forgot to simplify the matrix name, so that's just a type only here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Eigen, but I think it's complaining about the type of `imagePixels`.

```
Matrix<int, 240, 240>* imagePixels;
```

(I'm assuming the fact that you didn't initialize imagePixels with anything is a copy-paste error on the web, not in your actual code.)

All the examples of using the `()` syntax to access Eigen matrix objects are using the class a value type, not a pointer. Try it without the `*`, and see if that solves it for you.

```
Matrix<int, 240, 240> imagePixels;
//                   ^-- No "*"
```

### Edit

OK, so `imagePixels` is a member of your managed class. Managed classes are only allowed to contain other managed classes, managed handles (`^`), unmanaged pointers (`*`), or basic types (e.g., int). Unmanaged classes as a value type is not allowed.

There's two ways around this:

1. Leave `imagePixels` as a pointer, and dereference it each time you use the `()` syntax.

   ```
   (*imagePixels)(x,y) = y;
   ```
2. Declare a unmanaged struct to hold your matrix as a value, and have a pointer to that in your class.

   ```
   struct HolderOfUnmanagedThings { Matrix<int, 240, 240> imagePixels; };

   // In your managed class
   HolderOfUnmanagedThings* unmanaged = new HolderOfUnmanagedThings();

   unmanaged->imagePixels(x,y) = y;
   ```

Comment: I tried that before, and it will give me the "a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type" error.

Comment: See edit. You can either keep it as a pointer and dereference it everywhere you use it, or you can have it as a value type in an unmanaged struct.